# Discord.py commands error message on command

Tags: discord, discord.py

My commands work but it also shows this weird error message. When I did `p!help`, I would get the response and this error message:

```
​No Category:
  clean 
  help  Shows this message
  sudo  

Type p!help command for more info on a command.
You can also type p!help category for more info on a category.
```

Comment: That's not an error, that's the default help command message

Comment: Can i fix it? like how do i get rid of it

Comment: You can remove it with `bot.remove_command('help')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the default help command by using `client.remove_command('help')`. You have to do this before you create your own help command.

```py
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='')
client.remove_command('help')
```

## Reference

- [`discord.ext.commands.Bot.remove_command`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.remove_command)

Comment: waw tysm :D ive been stuck with this for 2 days